# Why does the following equation hold?

Tags: summation, power-series

$\sum_1^\infty\frac{(k\theta e^{-\theta})^k}{k!}=\frac{\theta}{1-\theta}$,
where $0<\theta<1$.

It can be verified via simulation, but I haven't proved it.

Are there any previous results on this infinite sum?
Thanks!

Comment: For what range of values of $\theta$? For which $\theta$ does the series converge?

Comment: Yes, it should be $0<\theta<1$

Comment: Putting $x = \theta e^{-\theta}$, the left hand side is very close to the Lambert W function http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function .

Comment: Thanks, its done. The steps are as follows,$\sum_1^\infty \frac{(-kx)^k}{k}=-x\sum_1^\infty \frac{(-k)^{k-1}}{k} k x^{k-1}=-x W_0'(x)=-x\frac{W_0(x)}{x(1+W_0(x))}$. Note that $W(x)=W(-\theta e^{-\theta})=-\theta$.

Comment: Wait a minute, there's a factorial in the denominator in the question, but just $k$ in your comment. What gives?

Comment: It should be k!

Comment: Thanks. There is a factorial in the denominator. I forgot it.